# std::set<T>::erase(key). What if key isn't there?

Tags: c++, stl, set

if I erase an element from an std::set and pass the key, not the iterator, and the key isn't in the set right now, will an exception be thrown? The thing is every second sentence in the MSDN documentation says: "this does blah blah, but it doesn't conform to the standard". So I need to know the standard behaviour. I just couldn't find it in the standard. Redirecting to the relevant clause will do as well. Thanks.

Comment: btw, in my version of STL (SLTPORT) the function checks, but I need to know the standard behavior

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found this in section 23.1 (Container requirements):

> no erase(), pop_back()or
>   pop_front()function throws an
>   exception.

So `erase` can not throw an exception.

Answer (score 25):

```
size_type erase ( const key_type& x );
```

> **Return value**
>
> The function returns the number of
>   elements erased, which in set
>   containers is 1 if an element with a
>   value of x existed (and thus was
>   subsequently erased), and zero
>   otherwise.

(from [set::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/erase/))